# JavaScript window.location doesn't work in content editor webpart

Tags: javascript, html, dom, sharepoint-2010, content-editor

my issue is, that the following script with its window.location function doesn't work in a sharepoint content editor webpart. I've tested it as a standalone and it worked fine, but as soon as I've inserted it in the content editor webpart nothing seemed to happen when the script was executed.

I would appreciate any kind of help

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function redirect(){
       var search = document.getElementById('searchtxt').value;
       var url = "test.com/test.aspx?s="+search;
       window.location = "http://"+url+"";
       return;
    }
    </script>
    <input type="text" id="searchtxt"/> <input type="submit" value="Search" onclick="return redirect()"/>
```

Comment: Now I've found it out by myself:

I had to change the function call to

    <input type="text" id="searchtxt"/> <input type="submit" value="Search" onclick="javascript:redirect();return false;"/>

which means I changed `onclick="return redirect()"` to 

    onclick="javascript:redirect();return false;"

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `window.location.href` or `window.location.replace()`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I've tried several kinds of window.location and none of them seemed to work. I guess it is a problem with the content editor because the javascript is actually working. I don't know if it is helpful for you, but window.open() works fine, however window.open() isn't that what I'm looking for.

Comment: No, unfortunately not beause it is used for an intranet with no external access. This script (written in the content editor webpart on the page) is used to get the parameters from the search field and write it in the url after the ?s= tag, the filter of the list wich is also on this page reads the s parameter out of the url and gets in this way the search results.
I hope this makes things a little bit clearly for you.

Answer (score 0):

If the editor is in an iframe, you need to target the `top` window:

```
window.top.location = "http://"+url+"";
```

You should also make sure that the editor accept script tags (not all editors do).

Comment: Tanks for your answer, even if I target the top window nothing happens. The script per se should get executed because I can see alerts if I add them.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this `document.location.href='http://someurl.com/'`